# CFGRID Filtering with Checkbox

Tags: coldfusion, filter, cfgrid

I have created (with some help) a CFGRID with a Search Filter. This CFGRID displays a checkbox to select an ID. This CFGRID is editable, being that the checkbox can be selected to be passed as a selection list the only problem is that after the filtering fires the Checkboxes are cleared. Is there a way to keep the edit data on checkboxes persistent when filtering, without using a cfquery to save the data? Has anybody ran into this situation? suggestions will be greatly appreciated.